# Use group theory to calculate $9^{74} \pmod {13}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By Fermat's theorem (or more generally by Euler's totient function theorem), for $p$ prime, any nonzero element $a$ of $Z/pZ$ satisfies:

$$a^{p-1}\equiv1 \mod p$$

Hence, in this case, we have
 $$9^{74}=(9^{12})^69^2$$

Applying the theorem:

$$9^{12}\equiv1 \mod 13$$

So

$$9^{74}\equiv9^2 \mod 13$$

And now, if I'm doing the math correctly,

$$81=(13)(6)+3$$

So

$$81\equiv3 \mod 13$$

Is this correct?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial. Welcome!

Comment: $9^{74}\equiv4^{74}\equiv4^2\equiv16\equiv3\bmod13$

Comment: This is a special case of **modular order reduction** as described in the linked dupe. If you know some group theory you can reformulate that in more abstract language (I avoided that to keep it accessible to more readers). See the linked questions there for many more examples.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(13)=12$.  Fermat's little theorem gives $9^{12}\cong1\pmod{13}$.  Hence $9^{74}\cong9^2\cong3\pmod{13}$.

That is, you got it.